# I've forgotten the download Apple ID

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id

I bought one app and one app bundle on the App Store, but I forget what Appel ID I used.

I've tried several Apple IDs to find it, but can't find the one. I remember I connected it to my bank card, if that's useful?

How can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

First find the transaction on your bank account transactions summary. Then [contact Apple](https://getsupport.apple.com) and ask them to reference which Apple ID made that transaction.

They may not give you the full email, but maybe the first/last few characters may give you a hint.

Best of luck!